# Bootstrap Input Group Horizontal Align Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create an input field with a button addon appended, I've copied the code from the Bootstrap documentation but the input field and button seem to have opposite horizontal alignments. I've had a look at the applied styles in the Chrome developer tools but cab't figure out what's going on.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<div class="panel-heading">Checkins on @ViewBag.QryDate</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">Date:</div>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="@ViewBag.QryDate">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The image below shows the problem:

[image]

I am using an ASP.Net MVC 5 site which has Bootstrap 3 baked in, I haven't added any additional CSS or JS. I have replaced the Bootstrap 3 files with the latest ones available to see if it was a bug but that hasn't made any difference.

I have wrapped the .input-group in a .form-group as suggested in another SO question.

The issue can be replicated in Chrome and IE 11. Am I being a muppet? Any ideas what I've missed? Many thanks.

Comment: on my chrome and firefox  its ok - https://jsfiddle.net/L80vwhrc/4/

Comment: did you checked all the rules inherited in "Go!" with the inspect object option in chrome?¿?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions guys - after further investigation the following default style included in the ASP.Net MVC 5 Site.css was causing the problem:

```
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```